# Use Metabox to enter Post Title

Tags: custom-field, metabox

I would like to use a custom meta box to build the UI for the post title, instead of the usual field 'title' supplied on WordPress post screens.

I've build the meta box, the question is now how to save that field as the post_title. Anyone has done this before?

Comment: I recommend against this. Use the standard title field rather than a nonstandard version

Comment: Why do you want to create a new/separate UI for the post title? What are you trying to *accomplish*? Multi-line titles? Title/subtitle combinations? We need to know what you're doing in order to be able to answer this question.

Comment: I wanted to give it the appearance of a meta box, that's the main reason. But I could also think of a few other scenarios, like having HTML in the title.

Comment: Is it maybe possible to Change the "Enter Title Here" text?

Comment: I would also like to hide the slug and view post button that appear beneath the title by default.

Comment: This is also suggested by toscho in this post http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6818/change-enter-title-here-help-text-on-a-custom-post-type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it really necessary to override default Wordpress title filed? instead I'd recommend using a different meta key such as - `my_the_title` to store the title into database.

And then use wordpress function - [`get_post_meta()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta) to show it, instead of `the_title()` function.